# check age trigger from two separate tables in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, triggers

I need to create a trigger that checks that the age (in years) of the participant is higher than the minimum age of the race he/ she participates in. To do this I need to get information from the participants table and the race table. I need to add this trigger to the results table
here are my tables:

```
CREATE TABLE race 
( 
RaceID int, 
Location varchar2 (60), 
StartDate Date, 
RaceTime Date, 
MinAge int, 
);

CREATE TABLE participant
(
ParticipantID int,
"Name" varchar2 (60),
DateOfBirth date,
Sex varchar2 (1),
Age int
);

CREATE TABLE results
(
RaceID int not null unique,
ParticipantID int not null unique,
position number (2)
);
```

here is what I have created so far:

```
 create or replace TRIGGER dob_trg
  BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON RESULTS
  FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
RACE_MINAGE NUMBER;
PARTICIPANT_AGE NUMBER;
BEGIN
  SELECT RACE.MINAGE, PARTICIPANT.AGE
    INTO RACE_MINAGE, PARTICIPANT_AGE
    FROM RACE PARTICIPANT
   WHERE RACE.RACEID = :NEW.RACEID; 
  IF : NEW.AGE < : NEW.MINAGE THEN
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20000, 'Participant too young!');
  END IF;
enddob_trg;
```

However I'm getting the following error
Error(9,6): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ":"

Any help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

**Erros :**

Table race - there is an extra comma at the end of you MinAge col

```
CREATE TABLE race 
( 
RaceID int, 
Location varchar2 (60), 
StartDate Date, 
RaceTime Date, 
MinAge int, 
);
```

**Inside trigger errors:**

`IF : NEW.AGE < : NEW.MINAGE THEN` 
should be

```
IF :NEW.AGE < :NEW.MINAGE THEN
```

Your create trigger is on table **RESULTS** but the action is made on a column called AGE that belongs to the **participant** table .
Fix this logic before going forward.

One more error inside your trigger :

```
FROM RACE PARTICIPANT
```

add a comma between tables

### Fixed trigger

-here i what i think your trigger should look like ! 
Compile it and give it a try 
See my logic :
This query will store the values of minage using the predicate "NEW.ParticipantID"

```
  SELECT RACE.MINAGE, PARTICIPANT.AGE
            INTO RACE_MINAGE, PARTICIPANT_AGE
            FROM RACE, PARTICIPANT
           WHERE RACE.RACEID = :NEW.ParticipantID;
```

This part :- if the RACE_MINAGE is bigger or equal then

```
IF :NEW.AGE <= RACE_MINAGE THEN
        RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20000, 'Participant too young!');
      END IF;
```

**Complete trigger**

```
  CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER dob_trg
  BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON participant
  FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
RACE_MINAGE NUMBER;
PARTICIPANT_AGE NUMBER;
BEGIN
  SELECT RACE.MINAGE, PARTICIPANT.AGE
    INTO RACE_MINAGE, PARTICIPANT_AGE
    FROM RACE, PARTICIPANT
   WHERE RACE.RACEID = :NEW.ParticipantID;
   exception
  when NO_DATA_FOUND then
   NULL; -- or do something else you choose
  IF :NEW.AGE <= RACE_MINAGE THEN
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20000, 'Participant too young!');
  END IF;
  end;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Up_One
The trigger compiles but there is another problem
There are many participant that run in many races (& each race has its own min age)

Comment: Therefore if I want to add the row below to my participant table (like suggested in the modified trigger)
Oracle displays the following error messages:

SQL Error: ORA-01403: no data found
ORA-06512: at "SYSTEM.HORSE_DOB_TRG", line 4
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'SYSTEM.HORSE_DOB_TRG'
01403. 00000 -  "no data found"

Comment: insert into participant
(ParticipantID,"Name",DATEOFBIRTH,sex,AGE)
Values
('4','bob','10/Sep/02','M', '4');

Comment: Update your question with this comment ! for better formatting

Comment: I don't understand what you want me to do! You want me to edit the question that I posted originally?

Comment: i will do it ! for you :)

Comment: Ok! Also do you think I need to add a foreign key to reference the right participant id to the race id?

Comment: you should will speed up you query

Comment: there is no data found , so you need to treat that with an exception !

Comment: i have altered the trigger and added an exception

Answer (score 0):

```
IF : NEW.AGE < : NEW.MINAGE THEN
```

You should remove the whitespace after the : symbol.

```
IF :NEW.AGE < :NEW.MINAGE THEN
```

Also, it looks like you're missing a comma in your FROM clause:

```
FROM RACE PARTICIPANT
```

But that wouldn't make your code work yet, because you're testing the wrong fields in your IF statement. Also, you're not filtering the participantId.